# Generating function relation from the recursive equation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

How to show that the generating function $ S(z) $ of the sequence
$$\begin{eqnarray}
s_{n} &=& s_{n-1}+s_{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}
\end{eqnarray}$$

satisfies the relation
$$\begin{eqnarray}
S(z) &=& z S(z)+S(z^{2}) + z S(z^{2})?
\end{eqnarray}$$

I tried doing it like this:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
s_{2k} &=& s_{2k-1}+s_{k}, \\
s_{2k+1} &=& s_{2k}+s_k
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_k^{\infty} s_{2k}z^{2k} &=& \sum_k^{\infty} s_{2k-1}z^{2k} + \sum_k^{\infty} s_{k}z^{2k}, \\
\sum_k^{\infty} s_{2k+1}z^{2k+1} &=& \sum_k^{\infty} s_{2k}z^{2k+1} + \sum_k^{\infty} s_{k}z^{2k+1}
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_k^{\infty} s_{2k}z^{2k} &=& z\sum_k^{\infty} s_{2k-1}z^{2k-1} + \sum_k^{\infty} s_{k}z^{2k}, \\
\sum_k^{\infty} s_{2k+1}z^{2k+1} &=& z\sum_k^{\infty} s_{2k}z^{2k} + z\sum_k^{\infty} s_{k}z^{2k}
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{S(z)+S(-z)}{2} &=& z \frac{S(z)-S(-z)}{2}+S(z^2), \\
\frac{S(z)-S(-z)}{2} &=& z \frac{S(z)+S(-z)}{2} + zS(z^2)
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{S(z)-S(-z)}{2} &=& z(z \frac{S(z)-S(-z)}{2}+S(z^2)) +zS(z^2)
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
S(z)-S(-z) &=& z^2S(z)-z^2S(-z)+4zS(z^2)
\end{eqnarray}$$

But this does not result in what was expected, which is
$$\begin{eqnarray}
S(z) &=& z S(z)+S(z^{2}) + z S(z^{2})
\end{eqnarray}$$

Where am I making a mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: Just add the two equations
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{S(z)+S(-z)}{2} &=& z \frac{S(z)-S(-z)}{2}+S(z^2), \\
\frac{S(z)-S(-z)}{2} &=& z \frac{S(z)+S(-z)}{2} + zS(z^2).
\end{eqnarray}$$
(what you derived at is probably correct too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MatyMangoo wrote in a comment, just add together
\begin{eqnarray} \frac{S(z)+S(-z)}{2} &=& z \frac{S(z)-S(-z)}{2}+S(z^2), \\ \frac{S(z)-S(-z)}{2} &=& z \frac{S(z)+S(-z)}{2} + zS(z^2) \end{eqnarray}
and you get the expected result.